# How to subtract 6 months from today's date using JQ?

Tags: json, date, jq

I'm getting lost on how to subtract 6 months from today's date using JQ.

I know I can get today's date by doing `(now | todate | split("T") | .[0])` but from there I'm not sure the best solution to subtract 6 months.

Answer (score 3):

Use `gmtime` and `mktime` (see the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Dates)) to convert to and from a "broken down time", which is an array of items such as year, month, date etc. Substract, and re-assemble:

```bash
now | gmtime | .[1] -= 6 | mktime | strftime("%FT%TZ")
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/n3UxL1i7f4w)